# Does Major Cage Still Have the Reset Ability?

Tags: plot-explanation, edge-of-tomorrow

At the end of *Edge of Tomorrow*, after Cage kills the Omega and gets soaked in Omega blood, he regains his ability to jump back in time. We see that he dies and wakes up in the helicopter and all is well. My question is, **does Major Cage still have the reset ability**? If he were to die, will he be brought back to the point of waking up in the helicopter (or some other time)? Is there anything in the book or out of movie which definitively states any of this?

Comment: From what I have heard the movie takes a number of liberties when it comes to altering the plot. I haven't read the book yet, but from what I understand, the concept of loosing the time-loop ability is not present. The protagonist of the book tries to win the battle at hand (while saving others). I also heard (this is probably a spoiler) that the book ends in a somewhat bitter-sweet way. The protagonist manages to win the battle (and probably save many people), but the war continues. He won a battle, but is there anything he can do to win the war (even with the ability)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After thinking over the movie more, I am providing a second answer that is not necessarily contrary to my other answer.

The strongest evidence that Cage *does* retain the ability to loop is his final loop itself (at end of movie, when he wakes up in the helicopter near Big Ben). **Clearly his looping ability has been restored, and there is nothing in the movie to suggest that final loop was a one-time-only deal**.

The scene where the omega's blood interacts with Cage plays out nearly identically to the scene where the alpha's blood interacts with Cage, suggesting the same sequence of events is occurring. I believe this is meant to show that Cage got the looping ability from the omega in the very same way he previously got it from the alpha. **Same transmission method and same ability suggests same rules of retaining ability.**

Cage did not lose the original looping ability from the alpha until he bled out -- so **why would he have lost the second looping ability from the omega without having bled out?**

Comment: Well, both excellent answers, clearly a win-win for you (and everybody else, of course). ;-)

Comment: The way I understood it, the Alpha didn't have the ability to reset the day, the Omega did. By getting Alpha blood on him Cage somehow got _control_ of the ability (but it was still the Omega who _had_ the ability). - So I'm wondering: did the Omega initiate a reset with it's dying breath and Cage got thrown back with his memory intact because of the Omega blood. Or did the Omega blood actually transfer the ability (and not just the _control_ over the ability) to Cage.  Only in the latter case would he still be able to reset after his death.

Comment: I'll buy this answer a lot better than the other one you posted. I think both answer show a great deal of forethought before posting, which is awesome. Thanks for posting.

Comment: Does having this ability mean that Cage is now immortal?

Comment: Wait, you can answer more than once??? lol at me.

Comment: Clearly the Omega died first, if it had not and the alpha did, the day would have reset (to whenever exactly I don't know). Knowing this, and knowing that the Omega is the only creature that can actually reset time and that the alpha merely signals it to reset time we can speculate that in the scene where the Omega is killed followed by the alpha, that the two powers "mixed" and infected cage. Thus, in theory, he should have the ability to not only reset time, but to do so whenever he wants. Where the Omega was the reciever, and the alpha the transmitter, cage is now both.

Answer (score 5):

I think the events and symbolism of the movie suggest that, **at the end of the film, Cage *does not have the time-looping ability*, or at least *does not need it*. The loops have served their purpose: he has matured into a responsible, loving adult.**

Notice how the movie comments on the human maturity process:

At beginning of movie, Cage is immature and selfish. In a position of privilege during a time of crisis, he playfully flirts with the pretty young woman who greets him at the helicopter pad. Then he tries to avoid combat by blackmailing the general.

The time loops offer Cage a chance to mature. He makes a mistake but then starts over, avoids the mistake, instead makes a new one, and continues learning in this fashion. Over and over and over. Like any person making their way through young adulthood. He works hard, and along the way, he finally really gets to know other people, and their struggles.

At the point when the loops stop, Cage has matured. He has recognized the value of other people and is willing to sacrifice himself for them. He is self-assured because he has conquered his demons. He has fallen in love.

By the end of the movie, Cage has dispensed of the pesky "alpha" force that had him losing the same impossible battle every day (a young man coming to terms with the alpha-male urges of young adulthood) and moved on to conquer the more important "omega" force that was the true cause of the suffering (a mature man having figured out how to live life in harmony). At the same time, this maturity also means he no longer has the youthful ability to bounce back unharmed from mistakes. A wiser man, he appreciates his life much more, now that he has realized it is precious.

Comment: How extremely well-reasoned that answer may be, the more "physical" matters of the movie suggest that he still has the time loop facilitating Omega-blood, which can't really be discussed away much by his character development not needing it anymore. But since it seems to be abiguous in the movie if he still has the ability or not (as nobody dared to give a definite answer yet), I'll still give you a +1 for an interesting approach that at least *tries* to reason for an interesting, albeit not in any way definite, answer.

Comment: This is an interesting answer, but I think it is more opinion and conjecture than anything in or out of movie here which backs your thesis. Thank you for a well thought answer, though.

Comment: Sorry.
This isn't an answer, it's just a response to Shiz Z's 2nd answer (this site won't let me comment yet). What you're describing as 'human maturity process' is generally called character development. It's a device that adds an entire dimension of depth to a movie that would be all the more thin without it. For example: Star Wars. In the original, When Han Solo shoots Greedo 1st, we see a character that is primarily motivated by self interest and self preservation, not above murder if it serves him getting what he wants. However, throughout the movie, he gradually develops, to the point wh

Answer (score 4):

If the Omega had not died, I believe he would still have the reset ability. The Omega IS dead, however, and the Omega was the entity resetting time when the Alpha/Cage died. So while he does still have the reset ability in his blood, there is no Omega to perform the reset.

Comment: Yet, if it was the *Omega* that made the reset and he now has *Omega* blood (instead of the *Alpha* blood he had earlier), he might now posses the ability for reset himself, without needing an actual *Omega* to do it.

Comment: There's nothing to indicate he got the Omega ability, though, and since he DID get back the Alphas ability, there's no reason to believe anything more complicated happened.

Comment: Though it would be more complicated to believe he got the *Alpha*'s ability out of nowhere than the *Omega*'s ability from the blood which we clearly see he mixes his own with. But I agree that this isn't explained much in the movie anyway.